# cannot create .jar file from .m files by matlab deploytool

Tags: matlab, jar, executable

I am using Matlab 2014b. I am trying to create .jar file from  my .m files. I have installed jdk 1.7.0-79.  I also have added the path variable in the control panel. So my java-version and javac -version is working from command promt, windows.

In my matlab command window I have added JAVA_HOME and path by setenv command. 
and I can see both by getenv command

still I have the two following problems

1> javac command is unrecognized by matlab

2> java package option is not showing in the deploytool.

Any help in this matter would be helpful.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPPA7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trieing, but we are using the deployment tool from MATLAB to create the jar. No javac needed inside matlab.

http://de.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-net-application-with-matlab-code.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  but the 'Java Package' is not showing up for me.

Comment: In my case only C shared library and C++ shared library is showing in the deploytool. I need the Java Package option to be there

Comment: in this case, your licence may not cover this or it's need to be installed. I installed the complete package.

Comment: I am now using a new matlab 2014a and stil not successful  to compile it.. The question regarding this is  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368804/m-fileusing-matlab2014a-to-jar-file-conversion-not-working).