# m file(using matlab2014a) to jar file conversion not working

Tags: java, matlab

I have used  different matlab which has the feature, but still not successful to complete the jar file.. The problem is                                                                              I want to convert matlab function to jar file. I am  using matlab 2014a. and the java installed is jdk1.7. I checked java and javac from command window windows.Unfortunately it is giving error during the packaging process

The function which I want to convert is

```
function [a]= sjdhbuj()
a=6;
end
```

The  error in the log file it is giving

```
ant:
<ant>
  <mkdir dir="C:\Users\SPILAB2\Documents\MATLAB\sjdhbuj1\for_redistribution" />
  <mkdir dir="C:\Users\SPILAB2\Documents\MATLAB\sjdhbuj1\for_testing" />
</ant>
mcc -W 'java:sjdhbuj1,Class1' -T link:lib -d C:\Users\SPILAB2\Documents\MATLAB\sjdhbuj1\for_testing -v   C:\Users\SPILAB2\Documents\MATLAB\sjdhbuj.m   class{Class1:C:\Users\SPILAB2\Documents\MATLAB\sjdhbuj.m} 
Test checkout of feature 'Compiler' failed.

mcc failed.
```

Any hint to solve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

That's a license problem.

Try  `license('checkout','Compiler')` and check if it returns 1.

Comment: It is returning 1....  So It means the license is there.then what is the problem.. Then why it is the problem...                                   license('checkout', 'Compiler')

ans =

     1